# xcode - problems building iOS apps with XCode and Ionic 2

Tags: xcode, angular, ionic-framework

Im working on a mobile app uisng angular 2 and ionic 2 and im trying to build a demo for ios/iphone. I folowed the guide for "publichsing an app" on their website and did everything it asked. I purchased an Apple dev account, linked it tto XCode, and followed every step completely but when i go to archive the xcode project, it gives me this error.

> testApp has conflicting provisioning settings. testApp is
>   automatically signed for development, but a conflicting code signing
>   identity iPhone Distribution has been manually specified. Set the code
>   signing identity value to "iPhone Developer" in the build settings
>   editor, or switch to manual signing in the project editor. Code
>   signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.2'

I;ve never used xcode before, im not sure how to properly troubleshoot this but if anyone is familiar with this problem, can someone point me to how to get this fixed??

Comment: Have you logged in your apple acc through Xcode?

Comment: @Smit Yes i have, everything is linked

Comment: Okay than you can do is, when u open your project in xcode , go to general and then there is drop of team. select your account. Once done, do the build. And you shld be good to go.

Comment: @Smit Im gonna try that now! And just to be sure, the proper way to build is Product -> Archive? Or Product -> Build?

Comment: Product -> Build

Comment: @Smit And that generates the .ipa?

Comment: Yes, and then archive it. `Build` and then `Archive` is a safe and less prone to errors.

Comment: @Smit I tried that but it gave me the same error smh. my team is set and everything, should i change the team to the Team ID from the certificates and IDs on the developer website?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137576/discussion-between-smit-and-dezmen-ceo-sykes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may go through below steps to achive

Open the project in Xocde, and go to general

1) Under Team, select your account(apple)

2) Build

3) Archive

4) Go to Window from the top Menu, select organizer

5) Select the lastest archive from the list of archives (usally the latest is placed on top)

6) Click upload.

From here, you accept all the stuffs as and when read and approved.

Once uploaded, go to developer portal of Apple, and go to the app.

Go to Activty section and check if the build is available.(it might take some time)

Go to internal testing section, select your testers and the build. and click start testing on the top right hand corner.